# How do I write a Makefile rule to apply patches using Quilt?

Tags: makefile, patch, automake, quilt

I'm one of the developers of Inkscape.  We incorporate a few modified chunks of various free libraries, in our code-base and we'd really like to handle our patches to the software in a more maintainable way.

I've used the [Quilt patch tool](https://wiki.debian.org/UsingQuilt) to apply patches to upstream code in Debian packages, and we have considered using it in the build for Inkscape

i.e.,

1. Patch all relevant upstream files using Quilt
2. Compile source

This would allow us to maintain a pristine copy of the upstream library and a separate patch set, which we can then forward upstream.

My problem is that aside from the Debian documentation, I haven't found any examples of how to neatly include Quilt in a Makefile.  Can anyone point me to a project that does this?

We currently use Automake, so if there is an elegant way of running a "patch" rule before the main build, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I can't point you to a project which does that, but I've done that for myself before by creating a new patch (which would be the last one) that creates a file named `patched.txt` in some convenient spot.  The `Makefile` for a simple project looks like this:

```
CXX = clang
LDFLAGS += -lstdc++
CXXFLAGS += -Wall -pedantic --std=c++11

all: patched.txt myprog

myprog: myprog.o helper.o

patched.txt: patches/series
    quilt push -a

clean:
    rm *.o barcode 
    quilt pop -a
```

You may or may not wish to have `quilt pop -a` as part of the `clean` target.  In other projects, I've created a separate `revert` target which does only that.  I haven't incorporated that into a project which also uses Autotools, but it shouldn't be too hard.

In my case `patched.txt` is created manually using `date >patched.txt` so that it's easy to see the date of the patch set.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess it would be possible just to add `date > patched.txt` to the end of the `patched.txt:` rule rather than having it as a dummy patch in the quilt series.Does this Makefile correctly handle the dependencies though?  e.g., does it cope with out-of-source builds?  Really, I guess we'd need to implement something that creates a temp copy of the required files within the build location, patches them and then builds.

Comment: @AlexValavanis: the dummy patch is needed because of the way `make` works. It's the non-existence of that file that causes `quilt` to run.

Comment: Sure, but by generating the file at the end of the `patched.txt` rule in the Makefile, you'd be able to avoid adding it into the quilt series.  It could then be removed again in the `clean` rule.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now, and yes, that's a viable option.  Also, it's lightly documented but `quilt` does return rational return codes, such as when a patch fails.